# Let $A$ be a square matrix with eigenvalue $\lambda$ and corresponding eigenvector $x$, Compute $A^n x$.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How to evaluate the following?

$${\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
5&3\\
{ - 6}&{ - 4}
\end{array}} \right]^n}\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
3\\
1
\end{array}} \right] = ?$$

Comment: Take a look at the edited version. Is this your question? :)

Comment: Try to  change your matrix appearance,.rewrite it in a good basis.

Comment: Hint: $Ax=\lambda x$. $A^2x=A(Ax)=A(\lambda x)=\lambda(Ax)=\lambda(\lambda x)=\lambda^2x$. So $A^3x=?$

Answer (score 0):

Start finding the Jordan Canonical form of A, which in this case is just a diagonal matrix since eigen values are $\frac{1}{2}(9\pm i\sqrt{71})$, i.e. \begin{equation}
A=S^{-1}DS
\end{equation}
Then you have 
\begin{equation}
A^{n}=S^{-1}DSS^{-1}DS...S^{-1}DS=S^{-1}D^{n}S
\end{equation}
In this case since D is diagonal $D^{n}$ is just the diagonal matrix with eigenvalues elevated at the n-th power. So basically you're done, you only need to find the S matrix to diagonalize the matrix and you can calculate the power you prefer.